# Detach entity within entity from persistence context in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate persists modified entities at the of transactional methods, I can avoid by using session#evict(entity).

If I detach it from the persistence context, the entities whithin it will also be detached?

For instance, I have this classes:

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity{
      @Column(name = "email")
      private String email;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
      private List<Address> addresses;

      // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Address extends BaseEntity{
      @Column(name = "email")
      private String email;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
      private User user;     

      // getters and setters
}
```

If I detach a user object, but change the address object in it, will the address be persisted at the end of transaction? Like this:

```
User user = userDAO.getById(id);
session.evict(user);
Address address = user.getAddresses().get(0);
address.setNumber(number);
addressDAO.saveOrUpdate(address); //will this work?
```

Comment: Why would you want to (explicitly) detach the user? JPA keeps a copy of every loaded entity in memory, when the transaction commits it runs through the Persistence Context and finds the modified entities. This way nothing happens to User unless you modify him.

Comment: I omitted the lines that I change the user, perhaps I should add in the example. But I'm detaching it because I'm doing a bulk update, so I don't want each entity to be saved individually.

Comment: Detaching is done for each individual entity, unless you have ```CascadeType.DETACH/ALL``` causing it to propagate. saveOrUpdate() should be sufficient to make sure the Address changes reaches the database (but if it works like JPA it is not required, as any change to managed entities are track). However if you update an entity which has CascadeType.UPDATE, I think you could get in trouble this is propagated to a detached entity. What do you mean by *bulk update*? I have done transaction of 500MB in size, and never had to detach.

Comment: I'm updateing the status of many users at once, so I put the ids in a list and make a single query to update. I have to set the status anyway in the objects because the setter triggers a spring Event

Comment: Why do you think you need to detach the user after doing the update query, and before the transaction commits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities that are updated or deleted using a `EntityManager.createQuery()` are not loaded into the Persistence Context, this only happens for select queries, and when you use `find()`or `merge()`.

After you do an update or delete query your persistence context may actually be out-of-sync with the database, because the query doesn't update the entities which has already been loaded into the persistence context (you need to call `refresh()` to see the changes).

If you load a number of user (into the persistence context), and later do`Update User set status='active' where id IN (:ids)`, then you have not modified any of the users in the persistence context, you have only modified the database. To modify a user, you must modify the actually managed Entity by calling `aUser.setStatus('active'), when the transaction commits, JPA will check all managed entities against a copy created when it was loaded, and if anything has changed it will do an Update.

If you are loading 5000 objects into the Persistence it may take some time for JPA to run though the entity graph, and detect the changes when the transaction commits. If you didn't modify anything, and would like to speed up the change-detection, there are two ways to do this. Load your entities using a read-only query, this tells JPA that it does not need to keep a copy of the loaded entity. The other option is to call `EntityManager.clear()` to throw away all managed entities. However, if you are interested in performance, the best solution is probably to avoid loading the entities into the persistence context. As I understand you problem, you need to do a `Update User set ... where id IN (:ids)`and for that you only need the user's id so you don't need to load the user, you just need the ids, and therefore you can do `List<Long> ids = em.createQuery("select u.id from User u where ...", Long.class).getResultList();`

Hope this clarifies things for you :)

**EDIT:** this is written from a JPA perspective, but for hibernate  `EntityManager` just forwards directly to `SessionImpl`, so the behavior is exactly as described, except for `find()` being called `get()`in native Hibernate.

Comment: When you say a read-only query, you mean the annotation @Transactional(readOnly = true)? Then I do the "select id" query inside it, and pass as parameter to a not readOnly method, this would suffice?

Comment: If the entire transaction is read only, then your bulk update will not work. If you want a single query to be read-only, you probably need to use a `@QueryHint()` but query hints are vendor specific. If you only select `User.id` then you don't need a read-only query, since nothing is loaded into the EntityManager (as you id field is not an Entity). If you use Hibernate you can always set a breakpoint and check the `Session.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey`field, this will show you what is currently loaded into the Persistence Context.

Answer (score 0):

Since JPA 2.0

given an **EntityManager** you can call detach with the entity you want to be detached as parameter

```
void detach(Object entity)
```

more  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

if you use injection then you can inject an EntityManger in the service where you want to detach the required entity.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using EntityManager, but the sessionFactory from hibernate